# Continuity at $\infty$

Tags: calculus, continuity

What can we conclude about the continuity of function 
$$  y=\begin{cases}{\frac{x}{e^x}\quad x\in{\left(-\infty,+\infty\right)}\\0 \quad\quad x=\infty} \quad   \end{cases}$$defined in the domain $\left(-\infty,+\infty\right]$ at $\infty$ ?.
In this case can I conclude the function is continuous(one sided continuity) at $+\infty$

I am also interested to know an answer to DonAntionio's question "What's the neighborhood of $\infty$?."

Edited.

Comment: What does it mean for a function to be continuous at $\infty$? How are these functions even *defined* at $\infty$?

Comment: You can define your function at these points.

Comment: How, exactly, do you define those functionss at $\,\infty\,$ ? And what's a neighborhood of $\,-\infty\,,\,\infty\,$ in your $\,[-\infty\,,\,\infty]\,$ ??

Answer (score 5):

You can make the set $X:={\mathbb R}\cup\{\infty\}$ to a topological space which contains ${\mathbb R}$ as a subspace. To this end you have to define what the neighborhoods of $\infty$ are. A set $U\subset X$ is a *neighborhood of* $\infty$ if it contains $\infty$ and all sufficiently large real numbers, i.e., a set of the form $\{x\in{\mathbb R}\>|\> x>M\}\cup\{\infty\}$. In this way $X$ becomes homeomorphic to the interval $\ ]0,1]\ $.

When you define
$$f(x):=\cases{ x/e^x\quad&$(x\in{\mathbb R})$ \cr 0 & $(x=\infty)$\cr}$$
then $f$ is continuous on $X$.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x}{e^x}=0=f(+\infty)$

You are adding a point to $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty\}$. To give this union a topology so that it is homeomorphic to $(0,1]$, you take as open set the open set of $\mathbb{R}$ together with the complements of closed sets of $\mathbb{R}$ that are bounded from above. The latter are the neighborhoods of $+\infty$